# POST request to IoT edge port 15580

Tags: microsoft-edge, iot, azure-iot-edge

How to connect to workload_uri in IoT edge using port 15580? How to form Http header?

I want to connect to port 15580 and post request to edgeagent.

Comment: Why do you want to connect to port 15580. This port [used by the Edge Agent and 'iotedge' CLI to start, stop, and manage modules](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/blob/52ef77db24126bf473265fc09c53d35290a2dd6b/edgelet/contrib/config/windows/config.yaml#L94) and it is belongs to IoT Edge Daemon not edgeAgent.

Comment: so how to talk to the edgeagent from a sensor?

Comment: You can't talk to edge module including edgeAgent from non-edge-Module like a sensor. If you want to send sensor data to Azure IoT Hub you can [use Edge as a gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-as-gateway).

Comment: Thanks for the support. @RitaHan-MSFT is there a way to connect NodeMCU to the edge gatway

Comment: In theory, it is able to connect to the edge gateway like [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway-linux#installation-on-the-downstream-device) shows. But NodeMCU can directly connect to Azure IoT Hub. Here are some tutorials you can follow: [1](https://www.thingforward.io/techblog/2018-05-22-connecting-nodemcu-to-microsoft-azure-iot-hub-part-1.html) [2](https://www.hackster.io/glovebox/secure-sensor-streaming-over-https-to-azure-iot-hub-dba05d)